# iOS Home Screen Shortcut URL

Tags: ios, safari

I would like to save a URL to my home screen (iOS). The URL includes an authorization key that is handled on the Apache server that serves the site.

```
http://www.host.com/key-foo
```

When I navigate to this website and create a home screen shortcut, the URL of the shortcut ends up as:

```
http://www.host.com/index.html
```

This breaks the shortcut because the authorization key is required. They key is used client side (React JS) and the Apache config is there so that we still direct all requests to index.html. The relevant Apache config is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/key-(.+)$ /index.html [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost/"
```

How can I make my iOS home screen shortcut URL = `http://www.host.com/key-foo` (which, for the record, is the URL that is saved if I create a regular Safari bookmark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

There's a property in my ReactJS app's `manifest.json` that is read by my home screen shortcut:

```
"start_url": "./index.html"
```

Removing this property solves the issue and the home screen shortcut now has the correct (unaltered) URL of `http://www.host.com/key-foo`.